# encoding H.264 video (or similar) on the iPhone directly?

Tags: iphone, video

What's the best way to *encode* video (with audio) on the iPhone?  It looks like QTKit isn't available... so I might have to link with ffmpeg,  but ffmpeg doesn't look like it encodes H.264 (judging from their home page.)

If it is possible, I'm also curious how fast I can expect it to perform on the ARM.  I imagine it might take minutes to encode a 20sec movie.

Comment: See the solution for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563212/create-video-in-iphone/17138410#17138410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ffmpeg and mencoder will encode H2.264 videos when combined with [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html), but I'd imagine getting it all running iPhone would be an absolute nightmare, let alone the performance of it once you've got it running.

Comment: the GPL on the H.264 is a non-starter there too.  Shucks.

Comment: I am trying to encode H.264 video on iPhone too, have you found any workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: See the linked question and use of AVAssetWriter.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote an AVI encoder for the iPhone that used raw file I/O.  I just started work on a QuickTime encoder that encodes BMP data into a quicktime container.  If it is H.264 you want to encode, I would try making a server that uses QTKit and having your app connect to that for conversion.

Comment: hey, any update on this? I am looking for something similar, I have MJPEG AVI file created in my app and I would like to convert it to H.264 over the air. Please provide the server link if you have already completed the encoder.