# Create video in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to convert image sequences(ie,png) to video file in iPhone. How i can convert the images to video.

Regards,

Comment: Are you talking about an iPhone application takes images and generates a video based on them? What is the goal of this video, just to rotate through the images inside the application?

Comment: i have a sequence of images. i need to convert these images to iPhone compatible  video

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're asking. Are you wanting to write an app to run on iOS that will convert the images to video? Or are you wanting to take images you already have, and create a video from them that you can then view on the iPhone? If so, are you wanting to do this on the phone, or on a separate computer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are likely going to need something like [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore bad advice like "use ffmpeg". That would work on the desktop, but the [license issue](http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/) makes including ffmpeg source code in your iPhone app legally questionable. Apple provides a class named AVAssetWriter that you would use in your app to encode a series of images as h.264 stored in a .m4v quicktime container file. While the apple provided logic does work, it is not so easy to actually use and you will need to read quite a lot of documentation to get the code working. If you want to skip implementing it yourself (and likely save yourself 3 or 4 days of work), please consider using my AVAnimator library for iOS as the h.264 encoding logic is already implemented in the class AVAssetWriterConvertFromMaxvid. Once encoded as h.264, the video can be played with the standard player and it is small enough to upload to a remote server.